# Find the SYN and ACK flags from the TCP Packets By TCPDUMP

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, wireshark, tcpdump

I am new to tcpdump . I have the packets by running the `tcpdump` command and the packets in the following way as given below:

I want to know the connection establishment by using the SYN-ACK and connection Finished By using the FIN-ACK, So my question is where is Option(SYN,ACK,FIN) Fields in below packets.

```
06-09 12:56:42.586: I/System.out(2332):     0x0000:  4520 0069 8589 4000 5606 692f 1f0d 4ff5  E..i..@.V.i/..O�
06-09 12:56:42.587: I/System.out(2332):     0x0010:  c0a8 060c 01bb b246 314c e66d 11ac 881a  (...��F1L�m.�..
06-09 12:56:42.587: I/System.out(2332):     0x0020:  8018 004e 0573 0000 0101 080a 9125 1551  ...N.s.......%.Q
06-09 12:56:42.587: I/System.out(2332):     0x0030:  0015 0712 1703 0100 301b 2159 9492 b19d  ........0.!Y..�.
06-09 12:56:42.587: I/System.out(2332):     0x0040:  4cbd 687a b6a1 5702 d845 015c 08a7 adc6  L�hz��W.�E.\.���
06-09 12:56:42.587: I/System.out(2332):     0x0050:  dde2
```

Comment: Duplicate http://serverfault.com/questions/217605/how-to-capture-ack-or-syn-packets-by-tcpdump

Comment: thank you for your useful reply , but I am looking the data such as c0a8 060c(192.168.6.12) in above line in front of 0x0010. Here  I am finding the Option fields i.e SYN,ACK,FIN, please help me.